# How does this question need to be edited to be re-opened?

Tags: support, close-reasons, closed-questions

I edited [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/90297/understanding-implementation-of-ula-array-response-and-beamforming-techniques-in), and my edit was accepted, but it wasn't re-opened. I must misunderstand the process, because I thought that it would be re-opened. Is there still something wrong with the question? How can it be further improved to be re-opened?

I haven't done this before, so thanks for any guidance that can be provided!

Answer (score 1):

Usually there's a "vote to reopen" tag when editing. Not sure what happened there. It's reopened now.